# Trying to install ubuntu on a Lenovo ideapad 320. Install stops at "grub2" Installation

Tags: grub2, system-installation

I'm having trouble installing ubuntu on Lenovo ideapad 320. It freezes at "grub2" install point. I have a boot info summary here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/26492750/

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I solved it by booting into BIOS settings and then changing the boot settings to legacy and rebooting into the ubuntu usb from bios not uefi.   Solved....BAM!!!!  No hangups.

Answer (score 1):

I found that booting into the USB drive from BIOS does let one boot Ubuntu and begin installation, but in that case the Ubuntu installer does not "see" the Windows OS. It offers to install Ubuntu on a selected partition or reformat the entire drive, but does not afford the option to provide a dual installation. I am still searching for how to make the Lenovo laptop boot to the grub file.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same problem but succeed to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Lenovo ideapad 320, with following orders:

1.Download Ubuntu install .iso from the official Ubuntu Web

2.use rufus to create the bootable usb

3.Enter the BIOS through windows(systemsetting->start->setting->update and safety->resotre->restart now->advanced settings->UEFI Setting(please check with google)):

> Disable Security boot
>
> Disable Fast boot
>
> Boot Mode: Legacy , Legacy support
>
> set USB as the first boot option

if all the setting is correct then reboot, the usb shall reboot in Legacy mode and follow the installation steps of Ubuntu, the system should be installed without stuck in grub2.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Ubuntu 18.04.
I was facing the same problem. Now it is working fine with 18.04

Comment: "Now" it is working fine with 18.04.